# Pandas- Select rows from DataFrame based on condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, filtering

**DataFrame**:

```py
category  value   
A         25  
B         10  
A         15  
B         28  
A         18
```

Need to Select rows where following conditions are satisfied,
1. `category=A` and value between 10 and 20
2. categories other than A

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[(df['category'] == 'A') & (df['value'].between(10,20))]
print (df1)
  category  value
2        A     15
4        A     18
```

And then:

```
df2 = df[(df['category'] != 'A') & (df['value'].between(10,20))]
print (df2)
  category  value
1        B     10
```

Or:

```
df3 = df[df['category'] != 'A']
print (df3)
  category  value
1        B     10
3        B     28
```

EDIT: Join both conditions with `|` for `or`, dont forget add `()` to first conditions.

```
df1 = df[((df['category'] == 'A') & (df['value'].between(10,20))) | 
         (df['category'] != 'A')]
print (df1)
  category  value
1        B     10
2        A     15
3        B     28
4        A     18
```

Comment: I need the result in one data frame. What is the efficient way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure if understand, all results are in one `DataFrame` - `df1`, `df2`, `df3`. Can you explain more?

Comment: Those two conditions in one query to get the result. Result will have category A within the range and all the other categories data.

Comment: Expected df                                                                        category,value
B,10  
A,15
B,28
A,18

Comment: Please check edited answer - need add `|`, but first condition need one `()` more.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.                                                             
 df[((df['category'] == 'A') & (df['value'].between(10,20))) | (df['category'] != 'A')].      Is this the right way?

Comment: Yes, exactly.Thank you.