# Extract rows based on a condition - Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pandas

I want to extract all rows from a df where the 'route_id' = 6A.

This is what I have tried but it returns a syntax error:

```
 df.loc(df['route_id'] = 6A)
```

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.loc[df['route_id'] =='6A']`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas- Select rows from DataFrame based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632927/pandas-select-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've used the assignment `=` instead of equality test `==`. The `.loc` needs square brackets and I also added some quotes around the `'6A'`

```py
df.loc[df['route_id'] == '6A']
```